# Python: I want to execute shell commands using python script

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu

I want to execute shell command "objdump" using python for my research work
I have used `subprocess.call("command")` to execute linux command but its not working.

Sample code which i have tried is

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("date")
```

after the execution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that traceback is not from an Ubuntu system!

Answer (score 3):

You must do this:

```
subprocess.call('date', shell=True)
```

Actually, Shell does allow you to access to global variable and programs that are in $PATH and your shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("date", shell = True)
```

Comment: But when i am trying using IDLE its returning 0.